# Wait for an addSubview to be successful before adding another Subview

Tags: ios, swift, addsubview

I am trying to add multiple subviews to my ViewController using autolayout. So, lots of these views are dependent on anchors or another.

My class is below

```
class historyView: UIViewController {

    var resFrame : UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "historyFrame.png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

   var timeTitleView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        let titleTxt = NSLocalizedString("Time", comment: "")
        textView.text = titleTxt
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "BPG Nino Mtavruli", size: 20)
        textView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

    var timeResView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "BPG Nino Mtavruli", size: 20)
        textView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

    var dateTitleView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        let titleTxt = NSLocalizedString("Date", comment: "")
        textView.text = titleTxt
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "BPG Nino Mtavruli", size: 20)
        textView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

    var dateResView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        let comResClass = complileResults()
        let resTxt = comResClass.getResult(key: "date")
        textView.text = resTxt
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "BPG Nino Mtavruli", size: 20)
        textView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        showResults()
}

 func showResults() {
    showResFrame() 
    showTime()
    showDate()
}

func showResFrame() {
        view.addSubview(resFrame)
        resFrame.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        resFrame.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        resFrame.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
        resFrame.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        showTime()
    }

    func showTime() {
        showTimeTitle()
        showTimeResult()
    }

    func showTimeTitle() {
        let titleTxt = NSLocalizedString("Time", comment: "")
        timeTitleView.text = titleTxt
        timeTitleView.font = UIFont(name: "BPG Nino Mtavruli", size: 20)
        timeTitleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(timeTitleView)
        timeTitleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        timeTitleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.leftAnchor, constant: 175).isActive = true
        timeTitleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        timeTitleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    }

    func showTimeResult() {
        let comResClass = complileResults()
        let resTxt = comResClass.getResult(key: "time")
        timeResView.text = resTxt
        view.addSubview(timeResView)
        timeResView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        timeResView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.leftAnchor, constant: 255).isActive = true
        timeResView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        timeResView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    func showDate() {
        showDateTitle()
        showDateResult()
    }

    func showDateTitle() {
        view.addSubview(dateTitleView)
        dateTitleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        dateTitleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        dateTitleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        dateTitleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    func showDateResult() {
        let comResClass = complileResults()
        let resTxt = comResClass.getResult(key: "date")
        dateResView.text = resTxt
        view.addSubview(dateResView)
        dateResView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        dateResView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resFrame.leftAnchor, constant: 95).isActive = true
        dateResView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        dateResView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }
```

}

When the view appears for the very firs time the **resFrame** UI
ImageView appears but nothing else. Even though you can see it's meant to be adding sub views.

If I go back in Navigation and then come back again all the views are correct!

I put a blockpoint on the addSubview(dateTitleView) line and the code got to that line BEFORE I saw the resFrame image appear.

So, my suspicion is the views aren't appearing as they are trying to anchor on something that doesn't exist yet.

I had expected the functions to process in order. By that I mean showTime() wouldn't be called until showResFrame() was done. Is that not what is happening?

```
func showResults() {
        showResFrame() 
        showTime()
        showDate()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them earlier inside `viewDidLoad` / `viewWillAppear` not `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    showResults()
}
```

`viewDidAppear` is called when the vc's view appears , so you'll notice that addition

Comment: I originally had it this way be noticed that viewDidLoad was only called once. When the view VERY first appeared. I should clarify that this ViewController is part of a TabViewController. So, when I first go to this tab, viewDidLoad is called. I then navigate to another tab before coming back to this one and I don't see VDL called again. I had print code in there to verify when it was getting called.

Comment: do you have to refresh the addition of all those views Why ? , if so try `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I'll give that a go

Comment: That was It @Sh_Khan. Changing from DidAppear to WillAppear solved my issue. Thank you sir